# How to terminate a system process in C++ program?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to terminate one process, when I open this process, it built in my account and system.

Then I want to terminate this process using c++ program. My code could only terminate the process in my account, not in system. How could I change to terminate both?

My code is like:

```
PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
{
    while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        if (stricmp(entry.szExeFile, "tvnserver.exe") == 0)
        {  
            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);
            TerminateProcess(hProcess, 1);
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
        }
    }
}
CloseHandle(snapshot);
```

Comment: Run the process as the system.

Comment: Either that or elevate the process to admin.

Comment: I don't think Admin can do that either. Unlike Unix, Windows has no concept of root. SYSTEM may be the closest, but Admin definitely is not SYSTEM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have the required privileges to obtain a handle to the process, you can use the administrators special debug privileges to terminate the target process

Assuming you run as administrator you can enable the SE_DEBUG_NAME privilege on the current process, and you'll be able to terminate the target process. Alternatively could also take ownership of the target process as documented here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3fb9cb5d-8891-4ba6-a945-06009be51e40/terminating-a-process-from-system-account-when-privileges-are-not-sufficient?forum=vcgeneral

This uses the first solution, and works for me, when running it as administrator.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

NTSTATUS EnablePrivilege(wchar_t *privilege)
{
    HANDLE token;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES *tp = NULL;
    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &token))
        goto error;

    tp = (TOKEN_PRIVILEGES*)new char[offsetof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES, Privileges[1])];
    if (!tp)
        goto error;
    tp->PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp->Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    if (!LookupPrivilegeValueW(0, privilege, &tp->Privileges[0].Luid))
        goto error;

    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(token, 0, tp, 0, 0, 0) || GetLastError() != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        goto error;

    CloseHandle(token);

    return 0x0;
    error:
    if(tp)
        delete[] tp;
        
    return 0xC0000001;
}

int main()
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

    if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
        {
            if (wcscmp(entry.szExeFile, L"spoolsv.exe") == 0)
            {
                NTSTATUS result = EnablePrivilege(SE_DEBUG_NAME);
                if (result != 0)
                {
                    printf("could not set SE_DEBUG_NAME Privilege\n");
                    getchar();
                    return -1;
                }

                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);
                if (hProcess == NULL)
                {
                    printf("couldn't open process\n");
                    getchar();
                    return -1;
                }
                TerminateProcess(hProcess, 1);
                CloseHandle(hProcess);
            }
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(snapshot);

    printf("success!\n");
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I try the code, run the VS2012 as administrator, however my process tvnserver.exe in System still there. What the **SE_DEBUG_NAME** means?

Comment: Summing up the individual sizes of members of a structure does not necessarily produce the structure's size, as it ignores potential alignment rules. You should replace `sizeof(DWORD)+sizeof(LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES)` with `offsetof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES, Privileges[1])` (see [offsetof](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz4y9b9a.aspx)), to account for alignment and padding.

Comment: You're also leaking memory pointed to by `tp`. Since you have multiple exit paths, you may wish to use a [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead of a plain pointer.